# Calculate the characters from a combination

Tags: arithmetic, index-notation

Given a table with position - 2 character combination pairs like this:

```
1. aa
2. ab
3. ac
4. ad
...
27. ba
28. bb
29. bc
30. bd
```

Assuming there are unique combinations with two characters from the alphabet following the same pattern.

How do I calculate what is the first and second character of the combination, if I know the position. That is, how do I find position 28 holds `bb`?

---

**EDIT:**

The answer that also describes how to do the reverse, i.e find the position of a combination based on the pair is going to be the most useful answer.

Comment: should `ba` be $27$ if you are starting from $1$ and including `aa`?

Comment: @gt6989b Oh, I missed one character when counting. (Missed to write it). Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an alphabet `A = ['a','b',...'z']` and a permutation list `L = ['aa', 'ab', ..., 'az', 'ba', ... , 'zz']`, with the first index starting from 1. (BTW the arithmetic would be much cleaner if you start indexing from $0$, like in the C language, for example.)

Then, the permutations come in groups of $26$, so if you are given an index $k$, then

- the second letter is given by the offset of $k$ in the current 26-long block, so it is $A[(k-1)\pmod{26} + 1]$ and
- the first letter is given by  $A\left[\lfloor(k-1)/26\rfloor+1\right]$.

---

If you were to number starting with $0$, the formulae become

- the second letter is given by $A[k \pmod{26}]$ and
- the first letter is given by $A\left[\lfloor k/26\rfloor\right]$.

---

Another free update you get with C, for example, is that if you declare `int k, d = 26;` then `k/d` computes $\lfloor k/d \rfloor$ automatically, no extra flooring is needed.

---

**UPDATE**

The inversion is simple. If first letter has index $F$ and last has index $L$, the offset is given by

- $26F + L$ for $0$-based indexing (like C)
- $26(F+1) + (L+1) = 26F + L + 27$ for $1$-based indexing

Comment: Haha, I am implementing algorithms in C, bt dubs.

Comment: @Edenia see updates

Comment: Hmm `A[pos % 26]` doesn't return the correct first character.     `Afirst[(pos / sz) - 1]` and `Asecond[pos % sz]` works though

Comment: sz being the 26.

Comment: @gt6989b I think you wrote the reverse: the first letter is given by $A[\lfloor k/26\rfloor]$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri of course, tyvm, corrected

Comment: I suspected it is just the reverse formula but I was too scared to comment on it as the AP is too much more experienced than I am. Not to mention the reputation.

Comment: I added a bit of an update.

Comment: @Edenia see last update

Comment: Thanks for helping out and making useful posts and not abandoning it once you post it!

Comment: @Edenia thank you for your kind words -- hope you stay around and contribute to the site as well

Comment: I am really not that good at math, I will probably learn things from here occasionally, but I do contribute at Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

For the index $n$, the $(\lfloor \frac{n-1}{26}\rfloor+1)^{th}$ letter of the alphabet is the first character, $(n\mod26)^{th}$ letter of the alphabet is the second character.

Comment: so for the second, index's reminder of the length of the alphabet. Got it. Really useful, thank you. What is this called though? Didn't know what to search for.

Comment: It's even nicer with 0-based numbering (and doesn't require the unusual interpretation of $26 \bmod 26$ as 26).